# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \sin(t) (1- \cos(t)) \sqrt{\frac12 - \frac12 \cos(t)}\,dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \sin(t) (1- \cos(t)) \sqrt{\frac12 - \frac12 \cos(t)}\,dt$$

I know the solution is $0$, but I don't know how one gets this.

Comment: P&P: Periodicity and parity.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\sin t\left(1-\cos t\right)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos t} &= \frac{1}{2}\sin t\left(1-\cos t\right)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{1-\cos t} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\sin t\left(1-\cos t\right)^{3/2}\,dt
\end{align}
so let $u = 1-\cos t\to du = \sin t \,dt$ which makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: So does this go down to 0 when integrated with the limits? I can't get it to work?

Comment: $u(0) = u(2\pi) = 0$ so the integral will be $0$ in any case. But you can compute the integral and find the result you desire. But please follow the comment by Daniel where you do not have to compute the integral directly.

Comment: I get 1/2sqrt2 x integral u^(3/2) with the limits of 1 and 0, but this doesn't give 0, where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\cos(2\pi) = 1 = \cos(0)$. I am not sure how you are getting $0,1$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int_a^{b} f(t)dt=\int_a^{b} f(a+b-t)dt$$

Thus
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \sin(t) (1- \cos(t)) \sqrt{\frac12 - \frac12 \cos(t)}\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \sin(2\pi-t) (1- \cos(2\pi-t)) \sqrt{\frac12 - \frac12 \cos(2\pi-t)}\,dt=-\int_0^{2\pi} \frac12 \sin(t) (1- \cos(t)) \sqrt{\frac12 - \frac12 \cos(t)}\,dt=-I$$

Hence
$$2I=0$$
or
$$I=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You can set $t=2u$, so
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos t}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-1+2\sin^2u}{2}}=|\sin u|
$$
Since $0\le t\le 2\pi$ is the same as $0\le u\le \pi$, you can ignore the absolute value and your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\pi\sin2u(1-\cos2u)\sin u\,du
=
\int_0^\pi 4\sin^4u\cos u\,du=
\left[\frac{4}{5}\sin^5u\right]_0^\pi=0
$$

But there's a much slicker way: set $t=u+\pi$, so the integral becomes
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\sin u(1+\cos u)\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos u}{2}}\,du
$$
Set $f(u)=\sin u(1+\cos u)\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos u}{2}}$ and note that $f(-u)=-f(u)$.